# how to change color while tap down and change again when tap up

Tags: flutter, button, colors

we have button 8 white buttons.
want that while we press the main button few buttons needs to change their color to green,and while we stop pressing, the color of these buttons needs to change again to white.
we tried to use when tapdwon and whentapup but it didnt work.
we tried to save boolean value that change when the button is pressed and if it changed the color is changing.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Screen building third test.dart';
import 'globals.dart' as globals;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class LBulb extends StatefulWidget {
  const LBulb({super.key});

  @override
  State<LBulb> createState() => _LBulb();
}

final stopwatchD = Stopwatch();
final stopwatchR = Stopwatch();
bool chosen1 = false;
bool chosen2 = false;
bool chosen3 = false;
bool chosen4 = false;
bool chosen5 = false;
bool chosen6 = false;
bool chosen7 = false;
bool chosen8 = false;
int ver = 0;
List<int> lightsIndex = [];

class _LBulb extends State<LBulb> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    ver = oneOrThree();
    lightsIndex = randomLights(ver);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(lightsIndex);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[600]?.withOpacity(0.5),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/background2.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 60),
            const Text(
              "Please click on the appropriate light's button",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 40,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Alkatra'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 500,
                width: 810,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                      offset: const Offset(
                        7.0,
                        7.0,
                      ),
                      blurRadius: 10.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: screenBuilding(
                  distance: 310.0,
                  // Center button
                  centerButton: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Container(
                      height: 20,
                      width: 20,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        // while long tap
                        onTapDown: (details) {
                          // start the detection timer
                          stopwatchD.start();
                          // chose the number and index of the lights that will be turned
                          for (int i = 0; i < lightsIndex.length; i++) {
                            if (lightsIndex[i] == 1) {
                              chosen1 = true;
                            }
                            if (lightsIndex[i] == 2) {
                              chosen2 = true;
                            }
                            if (lightsIndex[i] == 3) {
                              chosen3 = true;
                            }
                            if (lightsIndex[i] == 4) {
                              chosen4 = true;
                            }
                            if (lightsIndex[i] == 5) {
                              chosen5 = true;
                            }
                            if (lightsIndex[i] == 6) {
                              chosen6 = true;
                            }
                            if (lightsIndex[i] == 7) {
                              chosen7 = true;
                            }
                            if (lightsIndex[i] == 8) {
                              chosen8 = true;
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        // when the player release the button
                        onTapUp: (details) {
                          // save the time of the detection time
                          stopwatchD.stop();
                          globals.detectionTime = stopwatchD.elapsed;
                          globals.detectionTimes[globals.numOfTurn] =
                              globals.detectionTime;
                          // reset the values
                          stopwatchD.reset();
                          globals.detectionTime = const Duration(seconds: 0);
                          globals.numOfTurn++;
                          print(globals.detectionTimes);
                          // update lights
                          // chosen1 = false;
                          // chosen2 = false;
                          // chosen3 = false;
                          // chosen4 = false;
                          // chosen5 = false;
                          // chosen6 = false;
                          // chosen7 = false;
                          // chosen8 = false;
                          // start the response timer
                          // this timer will be closed when the player will press
                          // the button of the correct light
                          stopwatchR.start();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // the lights buttons
                  buttonsFirstRow: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked1");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked2");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked3");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked4");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked5");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked6");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked7");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("clicked8");
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  // the first 4 light
                  buttonsSecondRowHalf1: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color:
                                (chosen1 == true) ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color:
                                (chosen2 == true) ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color:
                                (chosen3 == true) ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color:
                                (chosen4 == true) ? Colors.green : Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  // the other 4 light
                  buttonsSecondRowHalf2: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(500),
                            border: Border.all(width: 3)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Color turnLight(bool isChose) {
    if (isChose == true) {
      return Colors.green;
    }
    return Colors.white;
  }

  int oneOrThree() {
    final rand = Random();
    List<int> a = [1, 3];
    return a[rand.nextInt(a.length)];
  }

  List<int> randomLights(int ver) {
    final rand = Random();
    List<int> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    List<int> ans = [];
    if (ver == 1) {
      int temp = a[rand.nextInt(a.length)];
      ans.add(temp);
    } else {
      int temp1 = a[rand.nextInt(a.length)];
      a.remove(temp1);
      ans.add(temp1);
      int temp2 = a[rand.nextInt(a.length)];
      a.remove(temp2);
      ans.add(temp2);
      int temp3 = a[rand.nextInt(a.length)];
      ans.add(temp3);
    }
    return ans;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap the widget with `GestureDetector` instead of using button. You may find `onTapDown` and `onTapUp` options there